Minimal Neovim setup for C# auto-formatting (Windows)
As a follow-up to this question:
What I Want
I want a minimal Neovim setup that provides only auto-formatting for C# files (.cs, and XML files .csproj and .xaml):

Format on save
Format on paste
No need for IDE features (completion, diagnostics, etc.)

Current Environment

Windows
Neovim 0.10.2 (installed via choco install neovim -y)
Format should match Visual Studio/VS Code style

My VS Code Settings (for reference)
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  },
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DotJoshJohnson.xml"
  }
}

Questions

Which files do I need to create/modify on Windows?
What's the minimal configuration required for only formatting C# files?

I'm explicitly not looking for:

LSP-based completions
Diagnostics
Navigation features
Any other IDE-like functionality

Just want proper code formatting when saving files or pasting code from clipboard.

Welcome to [vi.se]!

Technically plugin requests are off-topic here; let me try to edit.

Hi @D.BenKnoble thanks for the edits. I'm not really asking for a plugin. But how to get autoformat upon paste and save that is compatible with Visual Studio.

After some research and testing, I found a minimal setup that provides auto-formatting for both C# and XML/XAML files using conform.nvim. Here's the step-by-step solution:
1. Install Required Formatters
First, install the necessary formatters:
# Install C# formatter
dotnet tool install -g csharpier

# Install XML formatter
pip install xmlformatter

Verify the formatters are in your PATH:
dotnet-csharpier --version
xmlformat --help

2. Configure Neovim
Create or edit %LOCALAPPDATA%\nvim\init.lua:
-- Bootstrap lazy.nvim
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local lazyrepo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  local out = vim.fn.system({ "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", "--branch=stable", lazyrepo, lazypath })
  if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
    vim.api.nvim_echo({
      { "Failed to clone lazy.nvim:\n", "ErrorMsg" },
      { out, "WarningMsg" },
      { "\nPress any key to exit..." },
    }, true, {})
    vim.fn.getchar()
    os.exit(1)
  end
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-- Basic settings
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.g.maplocalleader = "\\"
vim.opt.expandtab = true
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 4
vim.opt.tabstop = 4
vim.opt.autoindent = true

-- Set up XAML files to be treated as XML
vim.filetype.add({
    extension = {
        xaml = "xml",
    },
})

-- Setup lazy.nvim with conform.nvim
require("lazy").setup({
  {
    'stevearc/conform.nvim',
    event = { "BufWritePre" },
    cmd = { "ConformInfo" },
    keys = {
      {
        "<leader>f",
        function()
          require("conform").format({ async = true, lsp_fallback = true })
        end,
        mode = "",
        desc = "Format buffer",
      },
    },
    opts = {
      formatters_by_ft = {
        cs = { "csharpier" },
        xml = { "xmlformat" },  -- Works for both .xml and .xaml files
      },
      format_on_save = {
        lsp_fallback = true,
        timeout_ms = 2000,  -- Increased timeout for larger files
      },
      formatters = {
        csharpier = {
          command = "dotnet-csharpier",
          args = { "--write-stdout" },
          stdin = true,
        },
        xmlformat = {
          command = "xmlformat",
          args = { "--selfclose", "-" },
          stdin = true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}, {
  install = { colorscheme = { "habamax" } },
  checker = { enabled = true },
})

3. Test the Setup
Create test files with unformatted content:
:: Create an unformatted C# file
echo public class TestClass { public void TestMethod() { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); } private int _someField; public string SomeProperty{get;set;} } > Test.cs

:: Create an unformatted project file
echo ^<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Framework" ^>^<PropertyGroup^>^<OutputType^>Exe^</OutputType^>^<TargetFramework^>net48^</TargetFramework^>^</PropertyGroup^>^</Project^> > Test.csproj

:: Create an unformatted XAML file
echo ^<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Test Window" Height="450" Width="800"^>^<Grid^>^<Button Content="Click Me" Width="100" Height="30"/^>^</Grid^>^</Window^> > TestWindow.xaml

Open the files in Neovim and save them to trigger formatting:
:edit Test.cs
:write      " Should format on save
:edit Test.csproj
:write      " Should format on save
:edit TestWindow.xaml
:write      " Should format on save

You can also manually format using <Space>f in normal mode.
Features
This setup provides:

Format on save for .cs, .csproj, and .xaml files
Manual formatting with <Space>f
No LSP or completion features (minimal setup as requested)
Compatible formatting with Visual Studio/VS Code defaults
Works with both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects

Troubleshooting
If formatting isn't working:

Check formatter installation:

where dotnet-csharpier
where xmlformat


Check Neovim's formatter status:

:ConformInfo


Look for errors in the log:

:edit conform.log


I would propose to use: Neoformat
Neoformat support all the plugin manager (vim-plug, lazy, packer)
With the following configuration (nvim/init.vim):
augroup fmt
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePre *.cs,*.xaml,*.csproj undojoin | Neoformat
augroup END

For .Net In particular it can make use of csharpier if:

csharpier is installed
you have the following configuration (nvim/init.vim):

let g:neoformat_enabled_cs = ['csharpier']

For .Xml a number a formatter are supported in particular XmlLint
For pasting I would suggest:
nnoremap p p`[v`]=
nnoremap P P`[v`]=

This would re-indent the part your just past.
Remark: gp and gP operation past taking in account the current indentation of the line and in my experience it solve 99% of the problem I face when pasting.

Thanks a lot for the answer. Some noob follow up questions: 1. Does the above answer work on XML files too? 2. Is the formatting compatible with Visual Studio? 3. Will I have autoformat upon pasting and saving? 4. Are these compatible with .NET Framework, or just Core? 5. How should I install the plugin? Can I use Lazy?

For compatibility with Visual Studio or .Net Framework I can't answer. csharpier is a very established choice for C# but I don't know how much it does exactly the same as dotnet format.

I have adapted the solution for pasting and for Xml support.

Thanks a lot. I also posted an answer below. Do you think your solution is better? if yes then I will accept yours.

You answer is very good and at the end you need to be happy with the solution :-) Thanks for your contribution.

yeah, thanks a lot. though I have no clue if my answer is OK, apart from some simple tests I did.
